# no file t1lmtt.fd

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

When I compile my document I get the following warning:

```
No file T1lmtt.fd.
Font shape T1/lmtt/m/n undefined(Font) using T1/cmr/m/n instead
```

The warning refers to an embedded PDF I have which is an plot produced outside of LaTeX and contains axis titles, etc. I would like to make sure that all the fonts used on my final pdf are embedded into the document so that they come out exactly as I see them when they are off to the printer. How can I do this?

Comment: The warning you show cannot refer to an external PDF file you are including.  Please try to post a MWE that reproduces the problem, and specify which typesetting engine you are using.

Comment: Do you not have Latin Modern installed?

Comment: @cfr: how can i check this? i'm using pdftex

Comment: On Windows?  Unix?  Mac?  Have you got MikTeX?  TeX Live?  In any case, it seems that you *don’t* have the Latin Modern fonts installed.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? Latin Modern is included in TeX Live. For MikTeX, probably try looking in the package manager.

Comment: i'm on MikTeX.  so i need to install this font separately as part of some package? a bit confused

Comment: … Or give up using the Latin Modern fonts.  I imagine you have a `\usepackage{lmodern}` declaration in your preamble: what happens if you comment it out?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: indeed i do. what's the alternative/default.. computer modern?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: commenting that out changes the error to cmtt instead of lmtt

Comment: And if you switch back to `OT1` encoding?  You should also have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`: try commenting out this line too, just to see what happens.

Comment: You can use MikTeX's package manager to install packages or ask it to install them on-the-fly, but let's check that really is the problem first.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: uncommenting the `fontenc` package causes a bunch of errors with `\textquotedbl` being unavailable in OT1

Comment: The best approach is to reduce your problem to a Minimum non-Working Example (MnWE) and diagnose the problem that way. Such an example might be `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{lmodern}\begin{document}abc\end{document}`. Does that give you an error and, if so, what? If you don't have Latin Modern installed, you should be getting an error when `lmodern.sty` is not found. However, you don't seem to be getting that. So it may be a different problem to do with a well-known quirk of MikTeX which means the package is installed but the font maps are not updated. Use the minimal example to confirm.

Comment: OK, that’s normal.  But indeed, I asked a silly question: we already know that I do have Computer Modern Roman in T1 encoding.  Your TeX installataion seems to messed up quite a bit: perhaps you shouls reinstall it…

Comment: OK, the mwe that you suggested works fine with no warnings/errors. I thought it might be the pdf i'm embedding but that wasn't it either..

Comment: @cfr: No if the fd-file is not found this certainly has nothing to do with map-files. If T1lmtt.fd is not found then something is seriously wrong the the installation of lmodern and one need a minimal example and the log-file to find out what is going on.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, true. Apparently I wasn't thinking very clearly. But it is not surprising if `T1lmtt.fd` is not found, of course. At least, it won't be found on my system (but that's TL).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Or does MiKTeX name the files differently? Shouldn't it be looking for `t1lmtt.fd`?

Comment: @cfr: No miktex doesn't do any curious things here. Whatever is wrong is wrong on Alex side and as long he doesn't give more info it is useless to speculate.

Comment: @cfr: What is really strange, here, is the that OP claims that even the `t1cmtt.fd` is not found!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti But it seems to look for `T1cmtt.fd` which seems odd. Shouldn't it look for `t1cmtt.fd`? (Assuming the error is parallel to the `lmtt` one.

Comment: @cfr: Good point! I overlooked the capitalization!  How come that it finds `t1lmr.fd` then?  Consistently, it should look for `T1lmr.fd`…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I don't know. I don't even know if that's the problem or how MikTeX deals with case sensitivity. In some cases, TeX seems to ignore cases when searching. So perhaps the looking for is normal and the not finding is not. I really don't know. But `kpsewhich T1lmtt.fd` returns nothing on my system (TL).

Comment: @cfr: latex only writes in the *message* with an uppercase encoding, the code converts this first to lowercase before trying to load the file `\lowercase{%
         \noexpand\InputIfFileExists{\f@encoding\f@family.fd}}}%`. You should trust the latex team that they didn't overlook this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: what other info can i provide to help diagnose the issue? i am trying to create an MWE but so far have not succeeded

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Trust them more than their diagnostic messages, you mean? Yes, I do ;). But it would be helpful if the message told me the file it cannot find and that it cannot find a file which might or might not be different from the one named!

Comment: @Alex If you have `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble and the body of the document is just `\texttt{abc}`, do you get an error? You really should...

Comment: @Alex: I see you are still interested.  Well, tell me this: compile a file that contains just the following: `\newread\myteststream \openin\myteststream=t1cmtt.fd\relax \ifeof\myteststream \typeout{NOT found} \else \typeout{Found} \fi \stop` (nothing more, nothing less); does it display `Found` or `NOT found`?  And if you replace `t1cmtt.fd` with `T1cmtt.fd`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: t1cm11 not found, t1cmtt found

Comment: @cfr: that works fine, no errors

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, it was a typo: the comparison is between `t1cmtt.fd` and `T1cmtt.fd`… :-(

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: both are found

Comment: @Alex: Mmmh…  And nonetheless, you say that, when you deleted `\usepackage{lmodern}` from your file, yesterday, you got a warning about font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n` being undefined?  I cannot explain this.  BTW, if you repeat the above test with `\openin\myteststream=t1lmtt.fd\relax` (or `T1lmtt.fd`), what happens?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: both are found (t1lmtt)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: i'm installing the latest version of everything on another box and will try it there, see if i get these same probs

Comment: @cfr: that F16 non-embedded font disappeared after I installed the package cm-super

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti,  well it doesn't look like it's the installation. Tried on a different box with a fresh miktex and texstudio and i get the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42728/discussion-between-gustavo-mezzetti-and-alex).